# RESTful multipart/mixed with spring mvc

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, content-type, multipart

I wish to send two types of content within one call for my REST service; Is it possible to send a multipart/mixed message as plain text?

Im using the following in my code;

Header:
Content-Type:multipart/mixed; boundary="simple boundary"

```
      --simple boundary 
 Content-type: text/plain;name="file-data"

 This is implicitly typed plain ASCII text. 
 It does NOT end with a linebreak. 
 --simple boundary 
 Content-type: text/plain; name="file" 

 This is explicitly typed plain ASCII text. 
 It DOES end with a linebreak. 

 --simple boundary-- 
 This is the epilogue.  It is also to be ignored.
```

Ive sent this via POSTman. It will hit my spring controller that is:

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST }, value = "/multipart",
        consumes = { "multipart/mixed" })
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void multipartSplitter(@RequestPart("file-data") String file){


LOGGER.info("This is the file: " +file);
```

I have the following bean setting;

```
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

<!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
```

and using:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I am currently getting; "HTTP Status 400 - Required request part 'file-data' is not present." and "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

please advise

Comment: What RESTful resource consists of two parts?

Comment: im planning to merge two bits of data, from two different services that needs to go to the same end point - hoping i could do it in one go rather than two